# Folder Navigation Tree in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a gui with an embedded folder navigation tree, much like the one shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uILG7.png). Does tkinter provide any widget directly similar to this, or do I have to build it from scratch? If it's the later, do I use the treeview widget? How do I add icon support in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add icons in treeview while using **insert()** use image perimeter

you should read this https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html

you can try this:-

```
import os
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
def process_directory(parent,path):
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        abspath = os.path.join(path,i)
        isdir = os.path.isdir(abspath)
        if isdir:
            elements = tree.insert(parent,END,text=i,open=False,values=(abspath,),image=image_)
            process_directory(elements,abspath)
        else:
            if i.endswith(".py"):
                elements = tree.insert(parent,END,text=i,open=False,values=(abspath,),image=image_1)
            
            
            
root = Tk()
root.title("File Display")
image_ = PhotoImage(file="folder.png") # put here file name of folder image that you have
image_1 = PhotoImage(file="python.png")# put here file name of python image that you have


folder = "."

tree = ttk.Treeview(root,show="tree")
abspath = os.path.abspath(folder)
parent_folder = tree.insert("",END,text=abspath,open=True)
process_directory(parent_folder,abspath)
tree.pack()







root.mainloop()
```

You can see the output:-

[image]